# Textbook approach when moving directory and it's sub-directories to SP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, sub-site

I have a directory "Customer" on the network drive. X has several sub-directories :

```
Customer Daily Reports
Customer Monthly Reports
Customer Weekly Reports
Customer Yearly Reports
Customer Ad hoc data requests
Customer Big Customers
```

On Sharepoint I have created a sub-site "Customer".

The files saved in the sub-directories need to move to SP - What is the recommended approach ?

1. Create document libraries for each of the network sub-directories.
2. Create a single doc library called say "Reporting" and then create several folders equivalent to the sub-directories within the single doc library.
3. A different approach from the above two suggestions.

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan thanks for the edit - which approach would you take and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the second approach you listed. 
As when it comes to working with large list, it can become slow. 

But in the end of it all, you need to make sure the that structure you put the files in, is something the users can understand.

Please keep in mind when migrating your data

1. File Sizes
2. Invalid Characters in your file names

Comment: +1 your suggestion agrees with our SPadmin.